# Mysql Union Query Record result emptys column

Tags: mysql

I have a union query to get a Max date record from two tables

```
SELECT
  id,
  MAX(mx)            AS max_date,
  `assigned_user_id`
FROM (SELECT
        id,
        MAX(date_due)       AS mx,
        `assigned_user_id`
      FROM tasks
      WHERE `deleted` = 0
          AND `parent_id` = 'aa6f0330-7a17-572f-94b5-4a5db1a1201f'
          AND `parent_type` = 'Accounts'
          AND date_due >= CURDATE() UNION SELECT
                                           id,
                                           MAX(date_start)      AS mx,
                                           `assigned_user_id`
                                         FROM calls
                                         WHERE `deleted` = 0
                                             AND `account_id` = 'aa6f0330-7a17-572f-94b5-4a5db1a1201f'
                                             AND date_start >= CURDATE()) s
```

this would look into both calls and Tasks and get me the Futuristic Call or a Task, but when i run this and i have a Futuristic Call and task is older, i get NULL in `id` and `assigned_user_id` columns. How do i fetch the whole info for the MAX date record.

When i Run individual Queries, i get null for first one while a record in the second one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps I'm misreading the problem, or I'm missing something - in which case, write me a comment to let me know, and I can delete this post altogether.

But, the way I understand what you've written, you want to:

1. Get the single record in `tasks` with the given `parent_id` and `parent_type` and where `date_due >= CURDATE()` which **has the latest `date_due` value**.
2. Get that same type of record from the `calls` table (using `date_start` instead of `date_due`).
3. Of those two records, find the one record with the later date value.  Select the `id`, the date (as `max_date`), and the `assigned_user_id` from that record.

Your query (and sub-queries) could just order by descending date and fetch only the first record.

I'm thinking something like this...

```
SELECT id,
       mx AS max_date,
       `assigned_user_id`
FROM (
  SELECT id,
         date_due as mx,
        `assigned_user_id`
  FROM tasks
  WHERE `deleted` = 0
    AND `parent_id` = 'aa6f0330-7a17-572f-94b5-4a5db1a1201f'
    AND `parent_type` = 'Accounts'
    AND date_due >= CURDATE()
  ORDER BY date_due DESC
  LIMIT 1

  UNION

  SELECT id,
         date_start as mx,
         `assigned_user_id`
  FROM calls
  WHERE `deleted` = 0
    AND `account_id` = 'aa6f0330-7a17-572f-94b5-4a5db1a1201f'
    AND date_start >= CURDATE()
  ORDER BY date_start DESC
  LIMIT 1
)
ORDER BY max_date DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Yes with a little edit for correct use of curly braces and table alias this is the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use `UNION ALL`. To allow duplicate values, use the `ALL` keyword with `UNION`.

Comment: I have used that but that only gives me the max_date column value, the other two are still null

Comment: Use Group By clause as you are using an aggregate function.

Comment: Still that does not work, it gives two rows, while i need a single row  with the MAX date record.

Comment: Select from that table Max date record -

Comment: When i group on ID it gives me wrong result when i have multiple records in both tables.

Answer (score 0):

Select Max(max_date) from

(SELECT
  id,
  MAX(mx)            AS max_date,
  `assigned_user_id`
FROM 
(SELECT
        id,
        MAX(date_due)       AS mx,
        `assigned_user_id`
      FROM tasks
      WHERE `deleted` = 0
          AND `parent_id` = 'aa6f0330-7a17-572f-94b5-4a5db1a1201f'
          AND `parent_type` = 'Accounts'
          AND date_due >= CURDATE() group by id UNION SELECT
                                           id,
                                           MAX(date_start)      AS mx,
                                           `assigned_user_id`
                                         FROM calls
                                         WHERE `deleted` = 0
                                             AND `account_id` = 'aa6f0330-7a17-572f-94b5-4a5db1a1201f'
                                             AND date_start >= CURDATE()) s group by id)

as temp

Comment: `id` and `assigned_user_id` are required and can not be skipped. I would need these values associated with the Record whose MAX(mx) is returned.